# One route parameter with multiple values on ASP.net MVC route constrain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

**My Route :**

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Without Controller",
      url: "{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "myControler", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      constraints: new { id = new NotEqual("Home")});
```

**Custom Route :**

```
 public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private readonly string _match = String.Empty;

        public NotEqual(string match)
        {
            _match = match;
        }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            return String.Compare(values[parameterName].ToString(), _match, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0;
        }

    }
```

**Question :** I need to filter both "Home" and "Login" ids.How can I do it ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
constraints: new { id = new NotEqual("Home")});//I need to give "Login" also ?
```

Comment: Why not pass a CSV through and process it inside? i.e `NotEquals("Home,Login")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comments, something like this:

```
public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly List<string> _matches;

    public NotEqual(string matches)
    {
         _matches = matches.Split(',').ToList();
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return !_matches.Contains(values[parameterName].ToString());
    }

}
```

Then:

```
constraints: new { id = new NotEqual("Home,Login")});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use params

```
public NotEqual(params string[] matches)
{
    _match = match.Join(",", matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
    {
        string[] _matches;

        public NotEqual(string[] matches)
        {
            _matches = matches;
        }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            return !_matches.Any(m => string.Equals(m, values[parameterName].ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
    }
```

Then in your route config:

`constraints: new { id = new NotEqual(new string[] { "Home", "Login" })});`